# \glsentrytext does not autocomplete in TexStudio

Tags: texstudio, glossaries, auto-completion

I am using texstudio TeXstudio 2.12.22 (git 2.12.22) Using Qt Version 5.12.1, compiled with Qt 5.12.1 R and using glossaries library. When I use `\gls` autocomplete works and offers the glossary entries inside brackets. However when I use `\glsentrytext` it is neither completed nor entries are suggested. Although autocomplete does not work, the `\glsentrytext` command works well.

See the texstudio configuration below

[[image: screenshot of the configuration[1]]

What could be the reason? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The `\gls` command is defined in `glossaries.cwl` in line 371 as

> `\gls{label}#r`

where the `#r` classification enables the completion behavior you are looking for, while `\glsentrytext` is defined in line 156 as

> `\glsentrytext{arg1}#S`

without that classification and with `#S` even explicitly disabling auto-completion.

If you want the same behavior for both commands, you have to create your own `cwl` where you overwrite that definition by writing the line

```
\glsentrytext{label%ref}#r
```

After restarting TeXstudio, the completion should work the way you want it to:

[image]

See also my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/585485/163512).