# Parse a label defined inside a macro in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio

I defined this macro:

```
\newcommand\afigure[4][]{%
    \begin{figure}%
        \centering%
        \includegraphics[#1]{#2}%
        \caption{#3}%
        \label{#4}%
    \end{figure}%
}
```

TeXstudio has an auto-complete feature for labels, which is quite handy. However, when I use the above macro, the label I give isn't recognised by the editor, and so it does not appear on the list of auto-completable (sic) labels. Is there a way of telling TeXstudio to take the fourth argument there and consider it as being given inside a `\label` macro? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TeXstudio uses `.cwl` files for auto-completion, which are usually auto-generated, but you can also create your own.
According to the [TeXstudio manual](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/master/utilities/manual/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION), they are stored in `%appdata%\texstudio\completion\user` or `.config/texstudio/completion/user` by default, depending on your OS. If you have made a custom installation, search for `completion` in your TeXstudio folder.

Then, all you have to do is to create a file called something like `mycmds.cwl` in that folder and write the two lines

```
\afigure{imagefile}{caption%text}{label%labeldef}#g
\afigure[keyvals]{imagefile}{caption%text}{label%labeldef}#g
```

Then restart TeXstudio, and the completion should work the way you want it to:

[image]

Comment: This is not quite the answer, although it is certainly handy. This allows me to have `\afigure` in the autocomplete list of macros, but not the fourth argument of this command added to the list of labels of my document.

Comment: I have edited my answer to show the behavior achieved with these instructions. Isn't that what you described as your goal in your question?

Comment: Just in case, you could try to make sure the new ``.cwl`` is active by checking the respective box in ``Configure TeXstudio`` > ``Completion`` > ``Permanently active completion files:``

Comment: Thou art a gentleman and a scholar, and thou getst the cookie! Brilliant! :)

Comment: My apologies. This was my first bounty and I didn't know I had to manually award it. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer :). Not knowing this TexStudio feature dissauded me from using custom \fref ref-like command to refer figures.